# Update multiple rows with the values of multiple rows in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

TABLE 1 is like following

```
A  B
1  x
2  y
3  z
4  t
```

TABLE 2 is like following

```
A2 B2
1  k
2  l
3  m
4  n
```

I want to update `Table2.B2` rows 2 and 3 with the values `Table1.B` rows 2 and 3

so the resulting Table 2 would be

```
A2 B2
1  k
2  y
3  z
4  n
```

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/article/mysql/cross-table-update/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE table1, table2 
SET table2.b2= table1.b 
WHERE table1.a= table2.a2 
AND table2.a2 IN (2, 3);
```

**Updated**

```
UPDATE `table1`, `table2` 
SET `table2`.`b2`= `table1`.`b` 
WHERE (`table2`.`a2`- 4)= `table1`.`a` 
AND `table2`.`a2`> 4 
AND `table2`.`a2`< 9 ;
```

Comment: I think I wrote the question in such a way that leaded to misunderstanding. Sorry for that. The problem is not specific to 2 and 3 think in this way, I want to write constraints for both table. for example I want to copy the values of table1 where id is between 1 and 4 to table2 where id is between 5 and 8 for example.

Comment: Can't you just put an extra AND table1.a1 >= 1 AND table1.a1 <= 4, along with whatever other constraints you want?

Comment: You are right. But there is a problem. In table2, values of rows between 5 and 8 are all same and equal to value of table1's row 1. In other words rows 2,3,4 were not copied to table2's rows 6,7,8. Table2's rows 6,7,8 are equal to table1.row1 .

Comment: I do not think so because where clause was included `(\`table2\`.\`a2\`- 4)= \`table1\`.\`a\``. What's your query?

Comment: why this (table2.a2- 4) = table1.a and this table1.a >=1 doesn t have same effect. Your query is true and works. But when there is no mathematical relation between table1.a and table2.a2 table1.a doesn t iterate. Always the first value which is x is copied to all rows table2.b2 –

Comment: Because we're updating row 1 of table1 to row 5 of table2. That's view `SELECT \`table1\`, \`table2\` 
WHERE (\`table2\`.\`a2\`- 4)= \`table1\`.\`a\` 
AND \`table2\`.\`a2\`> 4 
AND \`table2\`.\`a2\`< 9 ;`